# Custom grouping based on column count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database with products having a product type and a product line (a group of product types). I have to calculate average sales of each product type and up to here it is easy:

```
df.groupby('Type')['Sales'].avg()
```

The problem is that some Types have low stats e.g. for new products. So, in this case, the business would like to use the product line average instead of a single product type average.

So essentially, I have to build a custom aggregate function that will change behavior based on the group count and by the way, when there are low stats, it will need to access information on the whole database.

What is the best approach for solving this?

I have already tried taking grouping and looping on it. It works but then I have to fill the values back into the table and I don't know how. The other approach is instead to create a custom aggregation function and pass it via .agg but I don't know how to make it.

```
group = df.groupby('Type')['Sales'].avg()
for name, group in tab_sales_per_machines:
    nmachines = group['Machine'].nunique()
    if nmachines < 5 :
        ... do stuff using df...
    else :
        group['Sales'].avg()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `apply` (to get a little more flexibility over the argument than `agg`):

```
def your_func(group):
    nmachines = group.Machine.nunique()
    if nmachines < 5 :
        ... do stuff using df...
        return stuff
    # default is to return Sales avg
    return group.Sales.avg()

df.groupby('Type').apply(your_func)
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this approach and I'll let you know if it works. In the meantime I already solved but my solution does not seem very elegant. It works but I'm surethere is a better way.

Comment: It looks like it's working. I had to use a lambda to pass the df to my aggregation function. `tab  = df[['Type','Sales','Product Line','Machine']].groupby('Type').apply(lambda r: myAggregation(r,df))`.  The only issue is that now I get out a table with only two columns: "Type" on which I grouped and the aggregation I defined. But I'd like to also output the product line and the count "Machine.nunique". Essentially two more columns with two different aggregation. Can I tell apply to use a different aggregation on the different columns and get them all out? With .agg() I can pass a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by looping on the groups. I post here my solution. It works but it does not seem the most elegant way to do it. In case anybody has a better idea I'll be happy to hear about it. N.B.: The function is a bit more complicated than this: I tried to strip it down to the essential that is need to understand.

```
def getSalesPerMachine(df) :

    groups  = df[['Type','Sales','Product Line','Machine']].groupby('Type', as_index=False)

    # Build the output table
    tab = groups.agg({'Machine':'nunique', 'Sales':'sum', 'Product Line' : 'max'})
    tab['Annual sales'] = np.nan  ## <-- Create the column where I'll put the result.

    for name, group in groups:

        ## If stats is low use the full product line (rescaled)
        nmachines = group.Machine.nunique()

        if nmachines < 5 :

            # Retrieve the product line
            pl = group['Product Line'].max()

            ## Get all machines of that product line
            mypl = df.loc[df['Product Line'] == pl]

            ## Assign to sales the total of the PL rescales for how many machines of the specific type
            sales = mypl.Sales.sum() * nmachines /  mypl.Machine.nunique()

        else :
            # If high stats just return the sum plain and simple
            sales = group.Sales.sum() 

        # Save result (this was where I was stuck before)
        tab['Annual sales'] = \
            np.where(tab['Type']==name, annualSales, tab['Annual sales'])

    return tab
```